# How to generate model with the table named "document" with the column of id:int, file:blob, status:enum, exp_date:datetime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activestorage

I am using Rails 6 with ActiveStorage. 
I have a table of User, Signee, Signature, Signature_template, Position and Document.
I have a table also named "signature_template" with the column of user_id:int, file:blob(this is my question with document), created_at:datetime and updated_at:datetime.

Answer (score 1):

You can create from your terminal

```
rails generate model Document
```

And then add migration file as follow

```
create_table :documents do |t|
  t.binary :file
  t.integer :status, default: 0
  t.datetime :exp_date
end
```

Rails will automatically create id so you don't need to create it

For binary type it depend with your your database system, here is mapping.

For some famous database system

- Database System Mysql will be created as blob,
- Postgres -> bytea
- SQLite -> blob
- Oracle -> blob

For enum you can create as integer, but then in your Document model
you should provide information as follow (change the status to follow your needs)

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: %i(draft verified published)
...
end
```

And here is some detail for column type in rails for your documentation type

```
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| column type |                        Description                            |
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| :string     | Limited to 255 characters by default, Might be case-sensitive |
| :text       | Generally unlimited length depending on database              |
| :integer    | Whole number, in contrast to :decimal or :float.              |
| :decimal    | Stored with specified precision. Use for math accuracy.       |
| :float      | Floating-point decimal number with fixed precision            |
| :boolean    | True or false.                                                |
| :binary     | Raw chunks of data saved in database-specific way.            |
| :date       | Year, month and day (no time).                                |
| :time       | Hours, minutes, seconds (no date).                            |
| :datetime   | Date and time stored together.                                |
| :timestamp  | Exactly the same as :datetime on Rails.                       |
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do i need to put has_one_attached :file to my documents and signature_template model? Thanks for the information you've given. So much appreciation.

Comment: between has_one_attached or has_many_attached it depend how you design apps, here the reference for your consideration https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#has-one-attached

Comment: In my case, my idea is to clone the docusign website

Comment: if one document record can only have one file attached then use has_one_attached, meanwhile if one document record can has many documents attached then use has_many_attached

Comment: Thanks. For the primary key, i will use uuid because i am using postgresql